# If $\lambda \perp \mu$ and $\rho \perp \nu$, then is it true that $\lambda \times \rho \perp \mu \times \nu$?

Tags: measure-theory, product-measure

> Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{N},\nu)$ be measure spaces.
>    Let $\lambda$ and $\rho$ be signed measures on $\mathcal{M}$ and
>    $\mathcal{N}$ respectively. Suppose $\lambda \perp \mu$ and $\rho
>  \perp \nu$. Then is it true that $\lambda \times \rho \perp \mu \times
>  \nu$?

I want to say that this is false. I tried thinking of an example, something like $\nu$ and $\lambda$ are the Lebesgue measures on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ and $\rho$ are Dirac measures on $\mathbb{R}$ at $0$, but I can't get it to work.

In this example, $\lambda \perp \mu$ and $\rho
 \perp \nu$. If we think of the first component space $\mathbb{R}$ as the $x$-axis, and the second component space $\mathbb{R}$ as the $y$-axis, then $\lambda$ gives a mass of $1$ to the $x$-axis and $\nu$ gives a mass of $1$ to the $y$-axis. So in the $xy$-plane, that is, $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, let $E$ be a set that contains all of the $y$-axis except $(0,0)$ and none of the $x$-axis. Then $X = E \sqcup E^C$ and $(\lambda \times \rho)(E) = 0$ since $E$ does not contain the $x$-axis, and $(\mu \times \nu)(E^C) = 0$ since $E^C$ does not contain the $y$-axis apart from the single point $\{(0,0)\}$, which has Lebesgue measure $0$. Thus, $\lambda \times \rho \perp \mu \times
 \nu$ and this is not a counterexample. (But I'm not sure if this reasoning is totally correct).

Comment: I dont think that the use of the symbol $\sqcup$ is correct: this symbol means that $A\sqcup B\equiv (A\times \{a\})\cup (B\times \{b\})$ for arbitrary $a\neq b$ of any chosen subset

Comment: I was using the square cup to mean disjoint union. In what context does the square cup have the interpretation you're giving?

Comment: as far as I know this is the unique interpretation for the symbol $\sqcup$. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union). I was using, sometime ago, the same symbol as you are using it, then I realized that this is not the intended meaning. However Im not totally sure that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $A\sqcup B\equiv A\cup B$, I will open a question about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the statement is true. Because $\lambda \perp \mu $ then there exists some $A\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\lambda (A)=0$ and $\mu (A^\complement )=0$. Similarly there is some $B\in \mathcal{N}$ such that $\rho (B)=0$ and $\nu (B^\complement )=0$.

Now let some $C\in \mathcal{M}\otimes \mathcal{N}$, then $C$ can be written as the following disjoint union
$$
C=(C\cap (A\times B))\cup (C\cap( A\times B^\complement ))\cup (C\cap (A^\complement \times B))\cup (C\times (A^\complement \times B^\complement ))
$$
Therefore
$$
\lambda \times \rho (C)=\lambda \times \rho (C\cap (A^\complement \times B^\complement ))\\
\mu \times \nu (C)=\mu \times \nu (C\cap (A\times B))
$$
where we used the fact that $A\times H$ and $G\times B$ are null sets for $\lambda \times \rho $ for any chosen $G\in\mathcal{M}$ and any chosen $H\in \mathcal{N}$, and a similar thing happens for $\mu \times \nu $. Hence $\lambda \times \rho \perp \mu \times \nu $.